# Symfony Rest cache control private instead of no-cache on stage, prod env

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.6

On stage or prod ENV my rest api get a false header (`Cache-Control: private` instead of `no-cache`).

I think there must be an listener or configuration which will overwrite it. When I add manually `Cache-Control: no-cache` it will end with `no-cache, private`.

My Vhost could not be the problem I did create a stage on my local to test it.

Any ideas to find this listener which overwrites my header?

Comment: Have you tried to debug through `Response::prepare()`?

Comment: at the end of my action the header is correctly only `no-cache`. I tried the prepare its the same only `no-cache` in cache control. but in browser network log there is `private`. I think some listener is overwritting my response object.

Comment: setting also the `max-age` header to `0` seems to fix that the browser don`t cache it. but still a mystery for my why cache control is different on stage to dev environment.

Comment: Symfony HttpCache active?

Comment: yes HttpCache is active

Comment: So maybe the HttpCache is adding the private to the cache control, because it is not explicitly defined in your response. By default it adds private if Authorization or Cookie header is present

Comment: yeah did have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#caching-rules-and-defaults but none of the headers for private was there. but the `max-age` did fix my caching problem on IE.